# if condition for a number multiple

Tags: c++, c, if-statement

I got an if condition as a multiples of 5, i need to check if condition until a value <= 10000. My if statement looks like this

```
// in main function
if(value >=0 && value <16){
    function(number,value);
}
else if(value >=5 && value <10){
    value-=16;
    function(number,value);
}
....  
// function
int function(int n, int value){
    return (n<<value)|(n>>(16-value))
}
```

Is there a better way to do this if statement. I am new to programming world and a bit curious to know how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: But what u want to do on the first and second case, we need to understand what u want....

Comment: what is the difference between all the branches?

Comment: There should be a function call for every branch by subtracting a factor Eg: if(value >=0 && value <5){
  value -= 2;functioncall(value);
 }
 else if(value >=5 && value <10){
 value -=5;functioncall(value);
 }

Comment: @user3979554 give more examples, we can't generate a pattern using only one example!

Comment: That's not a function call. Please show some examples of what you're really doing.

Comment: Add it to the question, don't try to put multi-line code in comments.

Comment: Is there any pattern? Why are you subtracting `2` for `0-5`, subtracting `5` for `6-10`? What do you subtract for `11-15`?

Comment: You can put all the `value -= X` statements in the `switch` statement, then just do one `functioncall(value)` at the end. That's less repetition.

Comment: There's no need for testing `value >= lowerbound` in each `else if`. If it were less than the lower bound, the previous `if` would have matched and we wouldn't get into the `else if`. So you only need to test `value < upperbound`.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Why is the range for your first `if` from `0` to `16`? You'll never fall into the second range.

Comment: the user is going to enter the value. If he enters a value >=17 and <=10000, I'm subtracting user enter value with a 16 multiple and calling a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the amounts you're subtracting from `value` into an array, indexed by the multiple of 5 for each range:

```
int subtract[] = [2, 5, ...];
if (value > 0 && value < 5*(sizeof subtract/sizeof(*subtract))) {
    value -= subtract[value/5];
    functioncall(value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you this sounds reasonable

Comment: So you need to do something special for values that are multiples of 16, in addition to checking all the ranges of 5? What the heck is this function all about?

Answer (score 1):

You could use function pointers.

```
typedef void (*func)();

func fpointers[] = {func1, func2, func3}

int check = value / 5;

fpointers [check] ();
```

Comment: he's calling the same function, just changing the argument value.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to evaluate the condition for multiples of 5 , I suggest you to use `swich  case`

```
int check = value/5;

switch(check)
{
   case 0:        // 0 <= value < 5
    // do things
   break;

   case 1 :       // 5 <= value < 10
    // do things ...
   break;

   .............


   default:
   break;
}
```

Comment: the problem is it will make 200 cases if i use this switch case, is there any better approach

Comment: Is there any pattern to what you need to do for each case? If they can be computed from `value/5`, then just do that instead of writing lots of cases.

Comment: Now I'm curious, how many cases are you trying to inspect? AND what you do exactly inside any condition? we need to understand that in order to help you reduce hard coding

Comment: I'm testing till the value <=10000

Answer (score 0):

> I got an if condition as a multiples of 5

To check if a number is a multiple of 5, use the modulus operator:

```
if (number % 5 == 0) ...
```

> i need to check if condition until a value <= 10000

This sounds like you need a loop.